# Difference in specifying a named function for handler or anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlers

When specifying a handler function in jQuery, is there a difference between specifying a named function for a handler or wrapping your named function in an anonymous function?

Specifying a named function:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", bar);
```

versus wrapping named function in an anonymous function:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  bar();
})
```

Comment: `this` will not be bound in `bar` in the second one.

Comment: To clarify @Barmar's comment, `this` *will* be bound in the second, but not to the element which was clicked. The main difference between the two is the calling context, which is what determines what `this` refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're almost equivalent. The equivalent version with the anonymous function would be:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function(event) {
    bar.call(this, event);
});
```

When jQuery runs an event handler, it binds the context to the target element. `this.bar()` passes that binding along to the function.

If you want to be able to remove a specific handler with `.off()`, you need to use the first version with the named function. If you use an anonymous function, there's no way to refer to it when removing it.

Comment: Are you sure you can chain `bar()` to an element ? How about `bind()` (or call / apply) ?

Comment: I'm not chaining anything. I'm just reproducing the way that jQuery binds `this` to the event target when it calls an event handler.

Comment: Do I have to use `bar.call(this, event)` to emulate it properly?

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it! `this` is a native DOM element, why would it have a `bar()` method? calling it with `call()` and setting the value of `this` would work fine.

Comment: I think jQuery does `bar.apply(this, arguments)` in `$.fn.on`

Answer (score 1):

Only if you want to be able to call the function again later.

Comment: Why can't he call `bar` later in the second version?

Comment: I misread the example. you're correct. 'bar' is still the same function, regardless of where it is called. I thought  in the second example he was placing the code for the function bar, not calling it.

Answer (score 1):

As other have said, a named function usually implies you have a reference to the function object, which allows you to easily remove the event handler without resorting to less eloquent  tactics.

But, a named function in general is nicer if you use javascript debuggers. It's really nice when looking at a stack trace if each stack frame has a sensible name instead of "annonymous function".

PS - you can name the function expression like so

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function bar() {
    // "this" will be bound to the clicked element
});
```

Giving you short syntax, a named function to later remove the event handler with, useful binding of "this", and better stack traces.